# Scraping JavaScript var from HTML using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm scraping a website's HTML after a "GET" request. I'm essentially trying to get a few tokens from the site. I'm using Beautiful soup since it's what I usually use but I can't seem to figure out how to get a javascript variable from the html. The tokens are in the HTML like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var accessToken = "WaX2wWBb9fkp+qVQf6ECq9JcOZJnCL3Y/furfevohpk=";
var ivString = "d2c5708bbcc6b53c23af6d2cdab9f4ab";
var encryptedFpAccountId = "zk/5H7Iz0cNQPxPadMgvDw==";
var accessTokenCode = "0";
var nextPageName="signup-retail"
```

I need to get what the accessToken, ivString, and encryptedFpAccountId equal. How should I go about scraping this?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Regex** to get your required variable.

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
s = """<script type="text/javascript">
var accessToken = "WaX2wWBb9fkp+qVQf6ECq9JcOZJnCL3Y/furfevohpk=";
var ivString = "d2c5708bbcc6b53c23af6d2cdab9f4ab";
var encryptedFpAccountId = "zk/5H7Iz0cNQPxPadMgvDw==";
var accessTokenCode = "0";
var nextPageName="signup-retail
</script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("script")
accessToken = re.search('var accessToken = (?P<token>.*);', script.string)
if accessToken:
    print(accessToken.group('token'))
ivString = re.search('var ivString = (?P<ivString>.*);', script.string)
if ivString:
    print(ivString.group('ivString'))

encryptedFpAccountId = re.search('var encryptedFpAccountId = (?P<encryptedFpAccountId>.*);', script.string)
if encryptedFpAccountId:
    print(encryptedFpAccountId.group('encryptedFpAccountId'))
```

**Output:**

```
"WaX2wWBb9fkp+qVQf6ECq9JcOZJnCL3Y/furfevohpk="
"d2c5708bbcc6b53c23af6d2cdab9f4ab"
"zk/5H7Iz0cNQPxPadMgvDw=="
```